# How to disable media picker bar

Tags: facebook-messenger, facebook-messenger-bot

Is it possible to disable media picker bar only when user typing on for my chatbot?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can disable to composer input, which will then disable to media picker, too. Looking at your screenshot you already use the persistent menu. It has a property (composer_input_disabled), see https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/reference/messenger-profile-api/persistent-menu/